# Android Studio Toolbar Icons disappeared after Update (Invoke Gradle Sync manually)

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to the latest stable version `Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2` from Electric El 2022.1.1 Patch 1. Now the gradle sync icon that was right next to the "Run" icon has disappeared (red frame, see picture). I tried to edit the toolbar but I didn't find any way to restore the original layout.
[image: Missing gradle sync icon]

How can I restore the original layout (see image below)? And is there another way to manually invoke gradle sync?

Original layout:

[image]